# .htaccess rewrite rule won't allow ' and @

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a rewrite rule that rewrites domain.co.uk/member.php?x=$member to domain.co.uk/$member

It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ member.php?x=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ member.php?x=$1
```

I've tried to just add ' and @ to the square brackets but then I get a 500 internal server error. I need these characters for peoples usernames

How do I do this?

Comment: Off topic: Adding a `?` will make the trailing `/` optional without having to write both lines: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is used to specify user and password in a URI string like this:

`http://user:passw...@host/path`.

You need to urlencode it: `%40`

Your path will be: `/user%40foo.com` or something like this

This should work

Answer (score 1):

From [RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> The characters ";",    "/", "?", ":",
>   "@", "=" and "&" are the characters
>   which may be    reserved for special
>   meaning within a scheme. No other
>   characters may    be reserved within a
>   scheme.

and:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special
>   characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>   reserved characters used for their
>   reserved purposes may be used
>   unencoded within a URL.

***What you should do:***

- Encode the '@' to `%40`.
- Escape the single quote like in the .htaccess like so: `\'`